# Check whether string contains a full word

Tags: ruby

Is there something in Ruby that returns true only if the string contains the whole word, in this case `'hello'`?

I don't want the behavior of `include?` which returns true if only some characters within a word are present:

```
'hello whats up'.include? 'll'
=> true
```

Comment: they bust be together or apart? Like should `"lal".include? 'll'` be true or false?

Comment: it should only return true if the whole word is present! In this case hello

Comment: you can just do `"hello"['ll']` and it will return `'ll'` if it's present. So it kinda does the same

Comment: `hello == 'hello'` => true and `hello == 'll'` => false or should `hello.something 'elohl'` => true work?

Comment: What do you want your word delimiters to be? In other words, in a string, what determines for you what a 'word' is versus the rest of the string?

Comment: @nemesv actually i have an sentence like: ' Hello guys, how are you?'

Comment: @JohnSmith then you should update your question with this information.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the Ruby string class and use a regex. It would be quite simple. (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html)

Comment: Then use string#split: `' Hello­ guys,­ how are you?'­.split.inc­lude? 'll'`
=> false
`' Hello­ guys,­ how are you?'­.split.inc­lude? 'Hell­o'`
=> true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
> 'hownowbrowncow'['now']    => "now" # will be nil if not found
```

And if you want it to require word boundaries...

```
'hownowbrowncow'[/\bnow\b/]  => nil
```

It doesn't really matter if it returns true or false, since anything other than `nil` or `false` will fulfill a conditional test.  If you really like true and false, well, you can turn an arbitrary expression into true or false a number of ways, one way is:

```
'now'.nil?  => false
!'now'.nil? => true
```

Comment: You can achieve case insensitivity by doing `'hownowbrowncow'[/\bNow\b/g] => 'now'`

Answer (score 3):

Lots of good ways to do this as others have given. Here's another way:

```
my_string.scan(/\w+/).include? "hello"
```

This would be a case-sensitive check. For case insensitive:

```
my_string.scan(/\w+/).map(&:downcase).include? "hello"
```

This will also work with a variable for "hello":

```
m_string.scan(/\w+/).map(&:downcase).include? my_word
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "Hello guys, how are you?'"
keyword = "hello"
print str.split.map  { |word| word.downcase }.include? keyword.downcase
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean only the alphabet, then you could

```
(! 'Wr4ngle'.gsub(/[A-Za-z]/, '').blank?)
```

That grep should be versatile enough for your needs

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking to simply do:

```
"hello" == "hello"
```

If you don't want the match to be case sensitive, you could use:

```
"HeLlO".downcase == "hElLo".downcase
```

If you are looking to see if a string of characters includes another string of characters, you could do something like this:

```
s1 = "hello"
s2 = "oelhl"

s1.split("").sort == s2.split("").sort #=> case sensitive
s1.downcase.split("").sort == s2.downcase.split("").sort #=> not case sensitive
```

Comment: I think op is checking if A includes B, not if A is == B